# How to send link_to parameters using POST on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, link-to

I have a link_to like this:

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Contrato", {:controller => "hotels", :action => "edit", :id => @hotel_id, :selected_tab => "4"}, :class => "new_link" %>
```

There's a way to send those parameters not using the query string for it? (using post instead of a get) ??

Thank you!

I already tried:

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Contrato", {:controller => "hotels", :action => "edit", :id => @hotel_id, :selected_tab => "4"}, {:method => :post,:class => "new_link"}  %>
```

And it keeps doing the same thing...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a supported HTTP verb in the method option.

`<%= link_to "link", {:method => :post ...} %>`

Comment: that just add "method=post" to my query string =S

Comment: place :method => :post outside of the block. Ex: link_to "link", @instance, :method => :post. That should work.

Comment: Your link_to statement is fine. The only problem I see is your :action => "edit" which responds to HTTP PUT not POST. Make sure your controller action can accept a POST, or change it to PUT if that's what you originally wanted.

Comment: Changing a rails restful action is not the best approach. Will PUT not suffice since the action is edit? Besides, if a browser doesn't support PUT, PUT is converted to POST on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add `:method => :post` to the options of `link_to`.

Here are the docs (for Rails 3, but I think this still holds true for Rails 2 also) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

**EDIT FOR UPDATED QUESTION**

`:method => :post` belongs in the HTML options, not the URL options.  This is not very obvious from the documentation.

```
<%= link_to "Nuevo Contrato", {:controller => "hotels", :action => "edit", :id => @hotel_id, :selected_tab => "4"}, {:method => :post, :class => "new_link"}  %>
```

Comment: doesn't work either =S ... actually it's setting the right form method... but it stills build the href of the link including the parameters... maybe I need to specify the parameters some other way?